# How can I fix a py2app error when building with py2app

Tags: macos-catalina, python-3.8, py2app, pyenv

Trying to build a simple wxpython app using py2app and using pyenv.  I created a virtual environment from whence I run the application and build with py2app.  It fails during building on a "no such file or directory" error.

copying file /Users/humberto.a.sanchez.ii/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -> /Users/humberto.a.sanchez.ii/PycharmProjects/gittodoistclone/dist/PyGitIssueClone.app/Contents/MacOS/python
error: [Errno 2] /Users/humberto.a.sanchez.ii/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: 'No such file or directory'

I have never seen py2app copying such a file or directory.   Any help would be appreciated.

I saw something similar here ([How can I fix the error which occurs while building app via py2app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544926/how-can-i-fix-the-error-which-occurs-while-building-app-via-py2app)).

But I am not using the Xcode python

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what the problem was.  When I *pyenv installed* the 3.8.5 version of python, I had not set this environment variable.

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-framework
```

So once I uninstalled it and re-installed with the above option *py2app* started working correctly again.  Mystery solved.